# Online Secure Message Centre Design

Tags: database, architecture, content-management-system

I've got a requirement for an Online Customer Portal Secure 'Message Centre' to allow the back and front office to communicate with their customers in a two way fashion once the Customer has logged in via a secure channel.

We have procured a CMS platform with this widget presentation layer out of the box that expects to connect to an API to handle the communication and persistence i.e., the CMS is stateless.

I was wondering how people have designed and solutioned this - my current thinking:

1. Shoehorn it into our backend CRM system via a REST API - this would need custom dev
2. Use an RDBMS (custom DB data model adhering to the message structure) and build a REST API over the DB to handle the customer interaction events i.e., read, delete, new message
3. Build a pure microservice architecture with persistence coupled to the service - i.e., adhering to the pattern - engineering wise we don't have this capability yet
4. Other obvious solution that I have missed?

Am sure this has been solved multiple times over, keen to hear what works best?

*One thing I forgot to mention, is that we are migrating from an old legacy system and will need to bring about 10GB of customer messages with us i.e., historical data; this data needs to migrate into the new solution.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However you implement the back-end, the key here is to spend time getting your REST interfaces 'right', before doing any coding. Try to breakdown the interfaces into small specialized interfaces that service a specific business-focused responsibility. Also, think about the data model abstraction and its representation in the HTTP payload, and how to cross-reference to other data, using links embedded in the data transferred over the interface. If you get the interfaces right, then you can swap out the implementation down the line.

It is impossible to say without a deep analysis of the options what is best way to go. Unfortunately you haven't really explained the full extent of the API required or the capabilities of your existing CRM, but I am assuming there would be useful business advantages to option 1, as it integrates with your existing systems and business process. Option 2/3 would need your office staff users to use a different system, requiring training/support, which to my mind doesn't seem ideal. Option 3 requires a significant amount of work (not just coding, but integration testing, deployment, orchestration etc!), and from your description of the task, it is not clear that there really is a need to go down this route. My very high level hunch is option 1, but you will obviously need to research whether there is appropriate mapping between the API you present to the CMS and the API that is available on the CRM. Also bear in mind the security model with the CRM and of course responsiveness/throughput.

Comment: Hi the4thamigo_uk - thanks for the detailed response, much appreciated! The CRM is new, along with the CMS  - we are going through a re: platform of systems. Trying to find the correct home without over engineering things